# Creating an incremental List

Tags: python, list, increment

When I try to create an incremental list from `a` to `b` ( so something like [1,1.1,1.2,1.3,...,2] (a=1, b=2), then I start having a problem with the specific code I came up with:

```
def Range(a,b,r):
    lst1=[]
    y=a
    while y<b:
        lst1.append(round(float(y+10**-r),r))
        y+=10**-r
    return lst1

print Range(1,2,3)
```

Here, `r` is the power of my increments `(10**-r)`. For `r=1` or `r=2` the code works fine and ends at [...,2.0]. But for `r=3` or `r=4` it ends at [...,2.001] and [...,2.0001] respectively. But then, for `r=5` and `r=6` it goes back to ending at 2. Is there something wrong with my code or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: Just read http://floating-point-gui.de/.

Comment: This is different. I get a whole extra element in my list that goes against the logic of that list (say, to get a element of 2.001, the lost has to take in y=2.000, but the logic in it is that y<2.000). Plus i did round the numbers up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> say, to get a element of 2.001, the lost has to take in y=2.000

That's not true; it's possible that y becomes, say, 1.99999999999997.

You check on `y < b`, but then add `round(float(y+10**-r),r)` to the list. It's of course possible that the first is true, but the second is still larger than b.

To see what's happening, remove the rounding, and look at the next-to-last number in your lists in the cases where it's going "wrong".

Comment: Ahhh. You clever person. Clever, clever person. Thank You very much. I would give you a muffin, but unfortunately I'm not in your vicinity at the moment.